# Need a MySQL join on like

Tags: mysql, join

I have a 3 table join where one of the joins needs to be on a LIKE.

Here are the tables with results.  The 3rd table, apps_channel_titles as `apps_freeform_form_entries_58` as ff, is only 1 row because its a checkbox array.

```
apps_channel_titles as t
    Title 1
    Title 2
    Title 3

apps_channel_data as d  
    545|~|Title 1
    546|~|Title 2
    547|~|Title 3

***apps_freeform_form_entries_58 as ff
    546|~|Title 2
    547|~|Title 3
```

The query i'm using below does not work.  I have tried it without the `CONCAT` but haven't had luck there either.

```
SELECT d.entry_id, 
       t.title, 
       d.field_id_95, 
       ff.form_field_558 
FROM   ((apps_channel_data AS d 
         LEFT JOIN apps_freeform_form_entries_58 AS ff 
                ON d.entry_id LIKE CONCAT('%', ff.form_field_558, '%')) 
        LEFT JOIN apps_channel_titles AS t 
               ON d.entry_id = t.entry_id) 
WHERE  t.channel_id = 37 
ORDER  BY t.title ASC
```

These are the results I'm getting from the above query.

```
    entry_id  | title     |  field_id_95    |  form_field_558
    545       | Title 1   |  545|~|Title 1  |  NULL
    546       | Title 2   |  546|~|Title 2  |  NULL
    547       | Title 3   |  547|~|Title 3  |  NULL
```

What I want is for for the results to appear like below

```
    entry_id  |  title     |  field_id_95   |  form_field_558
    545       |  Title 1   |  545|~|Title 1 |  NULL
    546       |  Title 2   |  546|~|Title 2 |  546|~|Title 2
                                               547|~|Title 3
    547       |  Title 3   |  547|~|Title 3 |  546|~|Title 2
                                               547|~|Title 3
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Peter T

Comment: Without the actual schema, it isn't clear what is going on.  You may want to use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to set up a test database and sample query for people to work from.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this predicate

```
    d.entry_id LIKE CONCAT('%',ff.form_field_558,'%')
```

will ever return TRUE, since entry_id appears to be an integer value (values `545`, `546`, `547`) and you are doing a match to form_file_558,  and that contains values e.g. `'546|~|Title 2'`, so that's effectively

```
    '546' LIKE '%546|~|Title 2%'
```

Maybe you meant to do something like this:

```
    '546|~|Title 2' LIKE '%546%'
```

Also, the predicate in the WHERE clause

```
    t.channel_id =37
```

negates the the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN.  The LEFT JOIN operation specifies says to return rows from the left side, along with matching rows from the table on the right side (in this case, `t`), for any rows that don't have a match, a row of NULL values will be returned for `t`. The predicate in the WHERE clause essentially says `t.channel_id IS NOT NULL`, which will exclude any rows where no match was found.

Making a couple of adjustments, we could return a resultset like:

```
entry_id  title    field_id_95    form_field_558  
--------  -------  -------------  --------------
     545  Title 1  545|~|Title 1  (NULL)
     546  Title 2  546|~|Title 2  546|~|Title 2
     547  Title 3  547|~|Title 3  547|~|Title 3
```

But those other rows you want to return, they don't "match" anything from the other two tables.